# When an instance of a class is created in itself, then why the statements in the constructor are not executed?

Tags: java, constructor, stack-overflow

When a class is instantiated, its constructor is called. In this example, I want to check when a StackOverflow error occurred. But the statements declared inside the constructor are not executed, why?
see the following code

```
public class StackOverFlowSampleMain {
    StackOverFlowSampleMain oomeSampleMain = new StackOverFlowSampleMain();
    static int x = 0;

    StackOverFlowSampleMain() {
        x++; //aren't these lines supposed to be executed?
        System.out.println(x);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StackOverFlowSampleMain oomeSampleMain = new StackOverFlowSampleMain();

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add a bit source code please?

Comment: Code added, sorry for the incomplete post. I am new to posting questions and hence learning

Comment: The constructor executes as soon as `oomeSampleMain` is initialized - which never happens.

Comment: I've got no idea what's going on here.  This is a crazy thing to do.  I wouldn't have thought this would compile.  It can't do anything good.  When you instantiate a ** StackOverFlowSampleMain**, it's going to create its **oomeSampleMain** member.  But that's a **StackOverFlowSampleMain**.  So that's going to create its **oomeSampleMain** member.  But that's a **StackOverFlowSampleMain** object.  So that's going to create its **oomeSampleMain** member.  And so on and so on.  What do you think this code should do?

Comment: @tkausl Can you please put some more light? Are you talking about instance variable or local variable?

Comment: This thing blows up!  I just ran it, and it does what I expected...it crashes the stack. - you've got infinite recursion going on here.  It never executes the constructor code because it never gets that far.

Comment: It will throws java.lang.StackOverflowError, cos you initialize oomeSampleMain in unnamed constructor in the second line. Why you put that line there without any reason?

Comment: @VijayDevda I would suggest that you use the debugger of your IDE to analyze the behavior of your class. It might seem a bit rude but in my opinion it is the best way for you to learn what this class do...

Comment: @baumfreund, good idea.  Put a breakpoint on the `StackOverFlowSampleMain oomeSampleMain = new StackOverFlowSampleMain();` line.  I think you'll see that it just keeps executing that line over and over and over again. - and you can put a breakpoint in the constructor, and see that it never makes it in there before the stack crashes.

Comment: @rockfarkas I knew it will throw StackOverFlowError. But I was thinking that constructor execution is required for initialization of the class. And it will throw an error only after few times the class has been initialized recursively.

Comment: Were you maybe wanting to make 'oomeSampleMain' static?  That would change everything.  Then there would be only one of those variables, and you wouldn't get the infinite recursion.

Comment: The field initializers run before the constructor, as you can tell.

Comment: @baumfreund,@rockfarkas Thank you for the valuable suggestion.

Comment: If you make that first field static, your code runs to completion.  It prints '1' twice, once for the initialization of the static member variable, and once for the instance you create in your main().

Comment: @Steve No, I purposely made it instance variable. Because my doubt was that error will be thrown only after some times the constructor of the class has been executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Member initialization happens before the constructor's body.
So when you create a `StackOverFlowSampleMain` instance, the first thing it does is to initialize its `oomeSampleMain` member. It, in turn, attempts to initialize its own `oomeSampleMain` member, and so on, until the program crashes with a `StackOverflowError`, so the incrementing of `x` is just never reached.

If you want to measure when the `StackOverflowError` occurs, you could move the code that causes it to the end of the constructor:

```
public class StackOverFlowSampleMain {
    StackOverFlowSampleMain oomeSampleMain;
    static int x = 0;

    StackOverFlowSampleMain() {
        x++;
        System.out.println(x);
        oomeSampleMain = new StackOverFlowSampleMain(); // Here, after x is printed
    }
}
```

Comment: Gee...wish I'd thought of that!  (tic) . [ Doesn't really matter, but this is an excellent case for clicking that 'Community Wiki' box, IMO ]